# Subtract total column in table2 from total column in table1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Table1

```
Color, Total
------------
Red,5
Blue,3
Pink,1
```

Table2

```
Color, Total
------------
Red,3
Blue,2
Pink,1
```

The desired result would be:

```
Results
Color, Total
------------
Red,2
Blue,1
Pink,0
```

How do I subtract total column in table2 from total column in table1?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/2498

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to join tables and subtract values:

```
SELECT t1.color, t1.total - t2.total as Total
FROM @Table1 t1 INNER JOIN @Table2 t2 
    ON t1.color = t2.color
```

Here is updated [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/2501/0)

Comment: This is great solution but http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/2513/0 it should handle cases when there may not be corresponding record in tables. You could expand it with `OUTER JOIN`. This is one example where my solution is slightly better ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use `JOIN`

```
DECLARE @Table1 Table (color nvarchar(4), total int)
INSERT INTO @Table1  Values ('Red', 5)
INSERT INTO @Table1  Values ('Blue', 2)
INSERT INTO @Table1  Values ('Pink', 1)

DECLARE @Table2 Table (color nvarchar(4), total int)
INSERT INTO @Table2  Values ('Red', 3)
INSERT INTO @Table2  Values ('Blue', 1)
INSERT INTO @Table2  Values ('Pink', 1)

SELECT t1.color,t1.total - t2.total as total
from @Table1 t1
join @Table2 t2
on t1.color = t2.color;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23b58/12)

Answer (score 2):

`JOIN` is good option, but let's think different:

**[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/2509/0)**

```
SELECT t.color, SUM(t.total) as total
FROM (
  select color, total  from @Table1
  UNION ALL
  select color, -total  from @Table2) AS t
GROUP BY t.color
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: Does this give any benefit (code clarity? performance?) in comparison with JOIN solution?

Comment: Thanks for another perspective ☺

Comment: @dotnetom Just compare execution plans. This is pure for fun solution.

Comment: @Rod I find one case where it is better than join, what if there is no record in second table? Then join solution will omit it like: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/2513/0